# React functional component reload

Tags: reactjs, hot-reload

I am developing react based single-page app.
Every component is React functional-based and there are 2 parts for login and main.
The following is my code snippet.

```
function App() {
    const [bLogin, setBlogin] = useState(false)
    useEffect(() => {
//...
    }, [bLogin])
    if (bLogin) {
// main 
    } else {
// login
    }
}
```

My problem is that my app goes back login status whenever update code so I have to re-login to test the main component every-time.
I remember once I updated code compomentDidMount function is called on the class-based component.
I think useEffect function should be called to just re-render the only current testing component whenever update code.
But my app came back init status so bLogin was reset to false but nowhere reset it in my app.
Is there any good solution?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you handle your session? Do you store some cookie/token?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. you mean auto-login whenever re-rerender component? It might be one solution but it's not a issue for login. My question is why my app goes to init status whenever I update code.

Comment: When user logins you have to have a way of keeping him signed in like session cookie or a JSON web token.